# Uploading non maven projects to nexus

Tags: jenkins

I'm new with docker and jenkins. I'm trying to upload a non maven project to nexus using the jenkins pipeline. Below is a snippet of my jenkinsfile script. I want to do a maven upload of the resulting docker build image. any help?

```
node {

  def app

stage('Clone repository') {
    checkout scm
}
stage('Build image') {
    app = bat "docker build -t myapp ."
}
stage('Test image') {
     bat 'echo "Tests successful"'
    }
stage('Deploy image') {
     "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this plugin before so this is my best guess. I am thinking the below plugin might help you do what you are looking for.

https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven

Configure your pom.xml to point to nexus repository

Usage - https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/blob/master/docs/usage.md

dockerfile:build     ------>             Builds a Docker image from a Dockerfile.
dockerfile:tag  --------->                 Tags a Docker image.
dockerfile:push -------->Pushes a Docker image to a repository.